# Reference on (semi)group generated by nonlinear map

Tags: semigroups-of-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A : X \rightarrow X$ a map which is not necessarily linear. I am interested in solutions to the problem of finding a family $(y(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ (or $t \geq 0$) such that:

- Each $y(t)$ is a map on $X$.
- $y(t + s) = y(t) \circ y(s)$ for every $s, t$.
- $y(0) = Id$, the identity on $X$.
- For any $x \in X$ we have that $f(t) = y(t)(x)$ satisfies $$f'(t) = A(f(t)).$$

I know that there are conditions to get that $f(t) = e^{tA}(x)$ when $A$ is linear and bounded. I am interested in the case when $A$ is not necessarily linear. More specifically, $A$ may be homogeneous and bounded, that is,
$$\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| < \infty.$$
Notice that in that case $e^{tA}(x)$ is well-defined, but I do not know if it is a solution to the problem.

Is there literature on that? Thank you very much!